# Getting variable value from one package to another package class

Tags: java, reference

I am trying to use value of a variable in CommonDefinations class in another HitMe class but due to some reason the value to varaible is showing as null in HitMe class. I am extending HitMe class with CommonDefinations class. Not sure what is wrong. below are the classes.
Class CommonDefinations

```
package com.abc.def;

public class CommonDefinations{

    public String sUrl = "www.yahoo.com"

    public String jobUrlCheck() {
        sUrl = (System.getProperty("CONTEXT_URL") == null ? sUrl : System.getProperty("CONTEXT_URL"));
        System.out.println("Base Url: " + sUrl);
        return sUrl;
    }
}
```

Class HitMe

```
package com.abc.ghi;

import com.abc.def.CommonDefinations;

public class HitMe extends CommonDefinations {

    @Test(priority=1)
    public final void hitMeNow() throws Exception {

    System.out.println("Url is " +sUrl);

    }
```

Comment: cannot reproduce. Works correctly for me.

Comment: Working fine for me. What `@Test` library are you using?

Comment: If you see, it wont go inside jobUrlCheck method.